# Weird difference in callstack between release and debug

Tags: c++, callstack

I'm trying to walk the stack of this sample program:

```
#include <windows.h>

void Func1()
{
    Sleep(1000);
}

void Func2()
{
    Sleep(1000);
    Func1();
}

void Func3()
{
    Sleep(1000);
    Func2();
}

void main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        Func3();
    }
}
```

In debug mode I get what you'd expect. Something like:
Sleep
Func3
main

In release mode (with frame pointer optimization enabled) I get the stack:
Sleep
main

Where did the function between "main" and "sleep" go in the release run?

Comment: It probably got inlined by the compiler.

Comment: Remember: call stack is a privilege that gets taken away once you enable optimizations. (Actually, you can simply disable FPO: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2kxx5t2c%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)

Comment: I know, but I'm actually trying to a FPO callstack. It's doable if you have the PDBs and that's what I'm trying to do. :)

Comment: Yep, they were inlined.  
I simply change the "Inline Function Expansion" to Only_inline and the missing function appears. :)

Comment: @Idov, you should post that as an answer, then accept it so people will know what the solution was.

Comment: @ldov, oh, sorry, FPO actually has nothing to do with call stack when you have symbols :).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function was inlined.
I simply change the "Inline Function Expansion" to Only_inline  (in VS2008) and the missing function appears. :)